# How to display all elements in a column using cmd.ExecuteReader from mdf data file in Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

[Here's my .mdf database file that has 5 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni5m3.png)

I want to add each of those values from my `Id` column in a list

```
Private Sub Read_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Read.Click
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()

        End If

        con.Open()

        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM tablekongbago"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While dr.Read

            element = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString()

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    MessageBox.Show(element)
End Sub
```

The problem is that I can only retrieve the last row of my `Id` column and not all of the values from my `Id` column using

```
element = dr.GetInt32(0).ToString()
```

If I try to iterate and turn it into

```
dr.GetInt32(1).ToString()
```

it displays nothing.

I want to create a collection of Id's to a List(Of Integer) I know how to create a list and a for loop but I don't know how can I retrieve all of my Id's from my Id column, what kind of code should I use if "dr.GetInt32(0)" is only for the last row of the Id column?, is there a way I can loop starting from the very first top row up to the last row of my Id column? I want something like "list[0] - referring to the first row and list[2] - referring to the last row, so that I can add it my List(Of Integer).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You are looping through the records (with your "While dr.Read" block), but on each iteration you're replacing the value of "element" with the "Id" from the row .... so that's why it APPEARS that you're only retrieving the last row.  How do you want the "element" variable to be populated with multiple "Id" values - do you want an array, or a collection, of "Id"s?  Also, you wouldn't be able to use "dr.GetInt32(1)" as your SELECT statement only has a single column .... the parameter that you're passing to GetInt32() is the column index (0-based), so you can only reference column zero

Comment: Further to Craig's comment, if you want to display all the `Id` values in a message box then it makes sense to create a collection, add items to it in your loop and then combine them into a single `String` before displaying that. That would most logicvally be done with a `List(Of Integer)` and `String.Join`.

Comment: Yes I want to create a collection of Id's to a List(Of Integer) I know how to create a list and for loop but I don't know how can I retrieve all of my Id's from my Id column, what kind of code should I use if "dr.GetInt32(0)" is only for the last row of the Id column?, is there a way I can loop starting from the very first top row up to the last row of my Id column? I want something like "list[0] - referring to the first row and list[2] - referring to the last row, so that I can add it my List(Of Integer).

Comment: *"I don't know how can I retrieve all of my Id's from my Id column"*. Of course you do, because you're already doing it. As has already been explained, the problem is that you are discarding the last one each time you get the next one. The point of the list is that you keep them all and use them when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a List of Integer and add the ids to your collection during each call to `dr.Read()`

```
  Dim ids = New List(Of Integer)()
  While dr.Read()
     ids.Add(dr.GetInt32(0))
  End While
```

Comment: Yup this codes works :), it prints all my Id's

Answer (score 2):

I cringe whenever I see `If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then`. Connections should be declared in the method where they are used. You should never have to question the `ConnectionState`.

You have executed your command twice. A Select in not a NonQuery. NoQuery is Insert, Update and Delete.

Your `While` loop keeps overwriting the `element` varaiable on each iteration so you only get the value in the last record.

Never write an empty `Catch` block. It will just swallow errors and you may get unexpected results with no clue why.

It is a good idea to separate you database code from you user interface code.

Create your connection and command with a `Using...End Using` block so you know they are properly disposed. Likewise with the reader. I like to do as little as possible with a reader because it requires and open connection and connections should be open for as short a time as possible.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Read_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Read.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = GetIds()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    Dim ListOfIDs = (From row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                     Select CInt(row(0))).ToList
    ListBox1.DataSource = ListOfIDs
End Sub

Private Function GetIds() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM tablekongbago;", con)
        con.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks a bit messed up. This should work:

Note that a sql command object is VERY nice.

```
It has a reader built in - you don't need to define one
It has the command text  - you don't need to define one
it has a connection object - again no need to create one (but you look to have one)
```

And using a dataTable is nice, since you can use for/each, or use the MyTable.Rows(row num) to get a row.

And a datatable is nice, since you don't need a loop to READ the data - use the built in datareader in sqlcommand object.

```
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("Select Id FROM tblekingbago", con)

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim MyTable As New DataTable
        MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        ' table is now loaded with all "ID"

        ' you can see/use/display/play/have fun with ID like this:

        For Each OneRow As DataRow In MyTable.Rows
            Debug.Print(OneRow("Id"))
        Next
        ' display the 5th row (it is zero based)
        Debug.Print(MyTable.Rows(4).Item("Id"))

    End Using
```